# SAMBA in Centos 7 doesn't starts

Tags: service, centos7, samba, systemctl

I'm new in installing services in centos and I have sume issue that I can't find the solution. I installed SAMBA with the comand

```
yum install samba samba-client samba-common
```

being root, but when I do

```
systemctl start smb
```

it shows me this errors when I do systemctl status smb:

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4CHx.png)

I'm desperate, please could someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem installing Centos 7 with xfce unstead of GNOME and it's work's perfecty. I hope this will help someone other.